# Select model based on amount of related models with certain conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `Post` that `has_many :comments`. Let's say `Comment` has the following field: `another_model_id`. I would like to select Posts, that have from 2 to 5 comments with `another_model_id = 10` (for example). I tried several constructions but with no success :(

Example of what I tried:

```
# Invalid SQL syntax error
Post
  .joins(:comments)
  .select("count(comment.another_model_id = 10) as comments_count)
  .where("comments_count BETWEEN 2 AND 5")
```

I have literally no idea where to dig. Is it possible to achieve that in a single query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Post
  .joins(:comments)
  .where(comments: { another_model_id: 10 })
  .group('posts.id')
  .having('count(comments.id) > 2 AND count(comments.id) < 5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) is the best practice for your scenario:

In your `Comment` model, you need to set the `counter_cache`:

```
belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
```

Then simply you can use this query:

```
Post.joins(:comments)
    .where(comments: { another_model_id: 10 })
    .where('comments_count > ? AND comments_count < ?', 2, 5)
```